# Variable within quotes fails

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using a variable in PowerShell to get Active Directory info.
The variable does not get the value I need in double quotes. What am I doing wrong?

The variable display correctly but in the `Move-AdObject` cmdlet the value 
is `$CN` and not `tok12`.

Here is the code:

```
$CN = "tok12"
$company = "acme"
$CN
$company

Get-ADGroup $CN | Set-ADGroup -Description $company

Start-Sleep -s 1

Move-ADObject -Identity "CN=$CN,OU=UnassignedPortalTokens,OU=Portal,OU=testdomain,DC=testdomain,DC=com" -TargetPath "OU=Customers,OU=testdomain,DC=testdomain,DC=com"
```

Error message:

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Kentest' under:
'DC=testdomain,DC=com'.
At C:\PSH\Newport.ps1:13 char:2
+ Get-ADGroup $company | Set-ADGroup -Description "$token"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Kentest:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Kentest' under: 'DC=testdomain,DC=com'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

Comment: Instead of `$CN` try `$($Cn)`

Comment: Your code worked just fine when I tested it. What system are you running this on, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: I am running this on Windows 7 Professional edition. The active directory command goes through but fails because the token does not have a value. I can put the command in write-host and it looks fine for some reason the AD cmdlet cannot handle the variable in quotes

Comment: Only 2 of the commands fail.  Maybe its a timing issue?

Comment: The error message clearly says that `Get-ADGroup` can't find a group with the given name in your AD. That's an entirely different problem from what you described in the rest of your question.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes one of the commands was a wrong group. the other issue was the variable wsa null and i had to remove and set it again from command line

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Comment: Yes...i don't see a flag to mark as answered

Comment: Nobody posted an answer, because from the code you posted it's still not clear (to me at least) what the actual problem was. Feel free to post the your resolution as an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Question remains quite unclear, but OP seems to have fixed the issue by himself:

> (...) one of the commands was a wrong group. The other issue was the
>   variable was null and I had to remove and set it again from command
>   line – Gary Seven